# Is it possible to generate Diesel schema for only specific tables?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using Diesel to generate some schema using this command from the [Getting Started guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started):

```
diesel migration run
```

Is it possible to only generate one table? Some of my tables do not have a primary key. And for development purposes, I want to use just one table right now, I don't need to generate the schema for all tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Configuring Diesel CLI](http://diesel.rs/guides/configuring-diesel-cli.html), create a `diesel.toml` file in the same folder as `Cargo.toml`. With that file, you can configure Diesel it like so:

```toml
[print_schema]
filter = { only_tables = ["dashboard", "admin_users"] }
```

You can then rerun the `diesel migration run` command.